# Problem installing sqliv on kali linux (for vulnerability detection)

Tags: linux, kali-linux, python, pip

Currently I want to install this library to find vulnerabilities in web applications and in this way be able to protect those that I have already created, the problem is that I already followed several tutorials and none of them give me a solution to its correct installation since I downloaded the github repository with git clone and then I did the pip install -r requirements.txt inside the downloaded folder but it marks many errors that I do not understand that they would be the following:

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-a4ntt7oq/lxml_05cf691aefd241ac8c79286fb90037c2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-a4ntt7oq/lxml_05cf691aefd241ac8c79286fb90037c2/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-vrc61fd1/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.9/lxml                                                                         
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-a4ntt7oq/lxml_05cf691aefd241ac8c79286fb90037c2/                 
    Complete output (568 lines):                                                               
    Building lxml version 4.3.0.                                                               
    Building without Cython.                                                                   
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.34                                                
    running install                                                                            
    running build                                                                              
    running build_py                                                                           
    creating build                                                                             
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9                                                        
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml                                                   
    copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml                                 
    copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml                            
    copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml                      
    copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml                           
    copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml                          
    copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml                             
    copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml                       
    copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml                        
    copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml                      
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes                                          
    copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes          
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/html                                              
    copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/html                      
    copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/html                
    copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/html               
    copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/html                  
    copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/html                 
    copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/html              
    copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/html               
    copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/html                     
    copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/html                
    copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/html                   
    copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/html                      
    copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/html             
    copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/html                  
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron                                     
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron
    copying src/lxml/etree.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml                                
    copying src/lxml/etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml                            
    copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml                           
    copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml                       
    copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes         
    copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes              
    copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes      
    copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes          
    copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes            
    copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes       
    copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes         
    copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes         
    copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes        
    copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes             
    copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes         
    copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes           
    copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes       
    copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes             
    copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes        
    copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes             
    copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes         
    copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes       
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources                           
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng                       
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng                                                            
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl                       
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl                                                                
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl                                                                
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1  
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1             
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1                
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1                                                                                              
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1          
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1              
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1                          
    running build_ext                                                                          
    building 'lxml.etree' extension                                                            
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9                                                       
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/src                                                   
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/src/lxml                                              
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/python3.9-RNBry6/python3.9-3.9.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/python3.9-RNBry6/python3.9-3.9.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -Isrc -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/lxml/etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/src/lxml/etree.o -w   
    src/lxml/etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx_modinit_type_init_code’:                              
    src/lxml/etree.c:230559:32: error: ‘PyTypeObject’ {aka ‘struct _typeobject’} has no member named ‘tp_print’                                                                               
    230559 |   __pyx_type_4lxml_5etree_Error.tp_print = 0;                                     
           |                                ^                                                  
        
                                                  ^                     
    Compile failed: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1            
    cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /tmp/xmlXPathInit5gpi5g5o.c -o tmp/xmlXPathInit5gpi5g5o.o                                                                             
    cc tmp/xmlXPathInit5gpi5g5o.o -lxml2 -o a.out                                              
    error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1                     
    ----------------------------------------                                                   
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-a4ntt7oq/lxml_05cf691aefd241ac8c79286fb90037c2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-a4ntt7oq/lxml_05cf691aefd241ac8c79286fb90037c2/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-vrc61fd1/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.9/lxml Check the logs for full command output.
```

It should be noted that the operating system where I try to install this is in Kali linu suu most recent stable version and within a virtual machine that was created with virtualbox.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pip
ImportError: No module named pip
```

Comment: what do you mean by `many errors`? ... there appears to be only one error

Comment: what is your specific question?

Comment: Looks like the version of lxml.etree that you’re trying to compile doesn’t like python 3.9.  Maybe install packages instead of compiling?

Comment: "SQLiv SQL injection scanner" *is a python2 application* . Please read https://www.andreafortuna.org/2017/11/13/sqliv-a-massive-sql-injection-scanner/